# Не работает форма отправки на сайте

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование, email

залил сайт на бесплатный хостинг бегет, там форма отправки работает и сообщения приходят на указанную почту. Затем залил сайт на турецкий хостинг и сообщения перестали приходить. У меня стоит условие, если ошибка отправки, то сообщение Спасибо за заявку не появляется. А тут получается, что сообщение всплывает, а письмо не доходит именно с турецкого хостинга до майл почты. В чем может быть проблема?
На всякий случай оставлю код формы:

```
      <form class="contacts__form">
              
                    <div class="contacts__massage" 
          style=" display: none;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          flex-direction: column;
          z-index: 10;
            margin-bottom: 0;">
                            Your application has been accepted!
                        </p>
            <img src="./good.svg" alt="">
                        <p class="contacts__info-text" style="font-size: 14px;
            color: #000000; 
            margin-bottom: 0;">
                            We will contact you soon!
                        </p>
                    </div>
              <div class="home-container03">
                <span class="home-text09 lng-more">Contact us </span>
                <input
                  type="name"
                  placeholder="Name"
                  name="name"
                  class="home-textinput input"
                 required/>
                <input
                  type="tel"
                  placeholder="Phone"
                  name="tel"
                  class="home-textinput1 input"
                  required
                />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Question..."
                  name="massage"
                  class="home-textinput2 input"
                />
                <button type="submit" class="home-button ">
                  <span class="home-text10 lng-contact">Contact us </span>
                </button>
            </div>
        
  </form>
```

```
<?php

$recepient = "ror.dym@mail.ru"; //Почта куда будут приходить письма
$subject = "Заявка с сайта ERCKAP"; //Сообщение
$headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: test.ru <test.ru>\r\n"; 

$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$phone = trim($_POST["tel"]);
$massage = trim($_POST["massage"]); //Поля

$message = "Имя: $name <br/> Телефон: $phone <br/> Сообщение: $massage";

mail($recepient, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

```
$(function() {

    /* Отправка заявки */
    $(".contacts__form").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "post.php",
            data: $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function() { //Если все хорошо, показываем сообщение об отправки и очищаем поля
            $(".contacts__massage").addClass("active").css('display', 'flex').hide().fadeIn(); 
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                jQuery("#contacts__form").trigger("reset"); 
                $(".contacts__massage").removeClass('active').fadeOut(); 
            }, 3000); 
        });
        return false;
    });


    /*Маска для инпута*/
     var telInp = $('input[type="tel"]');
     telInp.each(function(){
        $(this).mask("+7 (999) 999-99-99");
     });

});
```

Comment: Функция `mail()` может быть октлючена на хостинге.

Comment: Не подскажите как ее включить?

Comment: Через `php.ini`, но лучше свяжитесь с поддержкой хостера, может быть что такова политика хостинга для предотвращения рассылки спама. И предварительно проверьте при помощи `phpinfo()` или при помощи `function_exists('mail')` в этом ли причина и действительно ли `mail()` отключена.

Comment: Да, написано что mail и sendMail - disable functions. Теперь, главный вопрос, как их подключить)

Comment: Бизон Лазарев, самый оптимальный вариант воспользоваться библиотекой https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer и выбрать один из бесплатных SMTP серверов (например от Яндекс (туториал: https://iexexchanger.gitbook.io/iexexchanger/osnovnoe/uvedomleniya/e-mail-uvedomlenie/nastroika-smtp-yandex))